# Glassfish 5 error: GRIZZLY0205 Post too large

Tags: glassfish

GF5 build1, Java EE7 + Primefaces 6.1, trying to upload photo ~ 2MB in p:textEditor componnent I always get error:

Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: GRIZZLY0205: Post too large

Setting "Max Post Size" to -1 or any >1mljn value in Configurations - server config - Network Config - Network Listeners - http-listener-1 doesn't help. The same on GF 4.1

Answer (score 5):

This is a x-www-form-url encoded content so we need set parameter: max-**form**-post-size. This isn't exposed via the UI, but you can configure it using cmd:

asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-form-post-size-bytes=-1